# Unable to restart Rails 5 development Puma server on Nitrous.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

Nitrous.io is an awesome service and the uptime keeps getting better, but that also sometimes becomes problematic for me when I don't know the correct way to terminate my development servers. I just upgraded to Action Cable and thereby switched to using Puma, but I'm not sure how to kill the Puma server while on Nitrous.io

/home/nitrous/Academy/.bundle/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:255:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Comment: maybe `ps -ax |pgrep puma |xargs kill -9` ... i'm assuming that the process is called puma, though..

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically kill the puma server and start it again whenever I call "rails s" in development mode-I think that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

After downgrading the gem version and bundling:

```
gem 'puma', '~> 3.6.2'
```

if problem still persists,then try to kill the running puma process first:

```
ps aux | grep puma

2598 2.4 3.5 1017520 141400 pts/16 Sl+ 15:57 0:04 puma 3.7.0 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [rails-app]
```

Restart the app again and check puma processes

```
jaswind+ 2950 11.0 3.6 1020164 143996 pts/10 Sl+ 16:02 0:04 puma 3.6.2 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [rails_app_copy]

jaswind+ 2976 18.1 3.6 1020880 144788 pts/16 Sl+ 16:02 0:04 puma 3.6.2 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3001) [rails_app]
```